# Why it lost my narrow type in the nested function

Tags: typescript

when i narrow my type, it success in the first scope, but it came back at the nested function, does anyone konw why? thanks

```
class A {}
function fn(): void | A {}
function fn2() {
  let a = fn();
  if (!a) return;
  a; // type is A
  const fn3 = () => {
    a; // type is void | A, but i expect A here
  };
}
```

It can be fixed by const

```
class A {}
function fn(): void | A {}
function fn2() {
  const a = fn();
  if (!a) return;
  a; // type is A
  const fn3 = () => {
    a; // type is A
  };
}
```

But why let can't do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a limitation of TypeScript's control flow analysis, discussed in length at [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and in the answer to the linked question.  TypeScript doesn't know when `f3()` will be run and if the closed-over `a` is ever re-assigned, the narrowing could be incorrect.  A `let` might possibly be reassigned but a `const` cannot be, so that's why they behave differently (even though in fact `a` is never reassigned)